# Javascript - creating a function with two arguments and returning 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I need to write a function which takes two arguments - rows and columns. The purpose of this function is returning 2d array with given numbers and rows. I need to return the array by using the function. Here's a code:

I'm a beginner and every feedback will be strongly appreciated. :-)

I've checked StackOverflow, I've tried to google it, check appropriate websites - unfortunately, no luck

```
function create2Darray(A) {
            var columns = [];
            var rows = Math.sqrt(A.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                  columns[i] = [];
                  for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                        columns[i][j] = A[i * rows + j];
                  }
            }
            return columns;
      }
```

Comment: Your function only takes 1 argument.

Comment: please share input & expected  output

Comment: Your question is unclear. The code you have posted converts a 1D array to a 2D array matrix with equal number of rows an columns. But the title says you want to create a function with 2 parameters?

Comment: for an array, you need `columns[i].push(A[i * rows + j])`

Comment: (Ah, the code is probably [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16501723/3082296))

Comment: Seems that @adiga is right. Its a try to convert 1D array to 2D. If thats the case check out the updated answer.

Comment: @MaheerAli the code has nothing to do with the question btw. The title of the question from my previous comment is "*Javascript create a 2d array*". It's probably a homework question and they stumbled upon that question and posted the code

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with an object with the length and map with the second parameter the inner arrays.

```js
const
    getArray = (l, w) => Array.from({ length: l }, (_, i) =>
        Array.from({ length: w }, (_, j) => i * w + j));

console.log(getArray(3, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question statement doesn't match the code you tried. It seems you want to convert single dimensional array to 2D array. Your code is fine. But the problem is that **`Math.sqrt(A.length);` may return float and `i * rows + j` will become float and array don't have float indexes**. Just use `Math.ceil()` to fix

```js
function create2Darray(A) {
     var columns = [];
     var rows = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(A.length));
     for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        columns[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            columns[i][j] = A[i * rows + j];
        }
    }
    return columns;
}

console.log(create2Darray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))
```

The following two solution are for function which takes length and width.

```js
function array(l,w){
  let res = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < l;i++){
    res[i] = [];
    for(let j = 0; j < w; j++){
      res[i][j] = (w * i) + j
    }
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(JSON.strigify(array(3,2)))
```

A on liner can be made using nested `map()`

```js
const array = (l,w) => [...Array(l)].map((x,i) => [...Array(w)].map((x,j) => (i*w) + j))
console.log(JSON.stringify(array(3,2)))
```